# sending messages with handlers without queue or delay

Tags: java, android, handler, pusher

I am trying to send a message from one thread to my UI thread using a handler. I am sending messages using the pusher API (pusher.com). and they are coming in and I can see them coming in really quick but it takes a while for the UI thread to get the message through the handler and it queues them instead of send and release as soon as something comes in.

Is there a better way of doing this without handlers or a way to get rid of the queue so that as soon as a message comes in the handler handles it?

This is sending the message that has come in inside the thread

```
public void onEvent(String eventName, String eventData, String channelName) {

                  String sentence = new String(eventData); 
                  try {

                      Message msg = new Message();
                      Bundle b = new Bundle();
                      b.putString("message",sentence);
                      msg.setData(b);
                      // send message to the handler with the current message handler
                      mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.v("Error", e.toString());

                           }
                  Log.e("server Thread", eventData);
               // mHandler.obtainMessage(MakeLightActivity.PACKET_CAME,sentence).sendToTarget(); 


              }
```

and this is where I am reading it inside my UI thread

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {



            Bundle b = msg.getData();
           String key = b.getString("message");
          incomingMessage =  key;
            if (key.length() >= 30){

                Log.d(TAG, "key" + key);
            messageCame(key);
            }

        }




};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a better way
You must use an `AsyncTask` which handles the thread and the Handler's functionality.

```
private AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> imageLoader = new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>()
{
    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params)
    {
        // do the work and onPostExecute will handle the result
        return result; 
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(Result result)
    {
        // do whatever with the result on the UI thread instead of a Handler
    }

};
```

Comment: and I use that within my activity and move the code I have in my separate thread within that?